# InfiniBand RDMA

Tags: azure, infiniband, rdma

I am trying to use the InfiniBand on an A8 machine on Azure. The ping-pong test works fine, however, I can not run a simple RDMA-based program. I can find the device using `ibv_get_device_list(NULL)` but I can not open it using `ibv_open_device()`. Is it true that all RDMA based applications must use Intel MPI?

Comment: can you even list the RDMA device in system? I mean use ibv_list

Answer (score 3):

As of today, Azure RDMA instances only allow Intel MPI to utilize RDMA capabilities. This is why any general purpose RDMA app will not work.

The good news is that this is going to change soon, as Azure intend to introduce support for general purpose RDMA in the very near future (2018), so hang tight!

Comment: Yuval, do you know if Infiniband Verbs API will be available? Can you please provide source of your information?

Comment: Hi Andy, Azure is scheduled to support general purpose RDMA around fall of 2018. Here's a link to a presentation with a sneak peak to its capabilities (video will be posted here in a few days): https://databricks.com/session/accelerated-spark-on-azure-seamless-and-scalable-hardware-offloads-in-the-cloud

Answer (score 0):

For the record, Azure finally opened [IBVERBS API](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-compute/configuring-infiniband-for-ubuntu-hpc-and-gpu-vms/ba-p/1221351) for certain instance types.